# Populate HTML table with search value Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a json file, that will eventually be called from a server with an API. Currently am just calling from an object.

I am creating an HTML file with a table navigation, where each header element also has a search box and submit button.

I would like the table to be blank on start, and when one of the header values is searched (id, nickname, email, etc), the json value that *contains at least part* of that search will populate the table.

I am new to the Angular syntax and am trying to get an idea of how this would even work.

```js
(function() {

    var app = angular.module('tool', []);

    app.controller('searchController', function() {
      this.info = data.people;

      this.findId = function(idInput) {
        angular.forEach(that.id, function(value, key) {
          if (value.contains(idInput)) {
            // not sure what to put here.
          }
        });
      };

    });

    var data = {
      "people": [{
          "id": "2245231",
          "nickname": "heyyman",
          "email": "info@gmail.net",
          "lastIp": "127.0.0.1",
          "regIp": "127.0.0.1",
        }, {
          "id": "2245232",
          "nickname": "heyyman2",
          "email": "info2@gmail.net",
          "lastIp": "127.0.0.2",
          "regIp": "127.0.0.2",
        }
      };

    })();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<main>
  <table ng-controller="searchController as search">
    <thead>
      <tr id="tableNavigation">
        <td></td>
        <td>ID
          <input type="text" ng-model="idInput">
          <input type="submit" ng-click="findId(idInput)">
        </td>
        <td>Nickname</td>
        <td>Login / Email</td>
        <td>Last IP</td>
        <td>Registration IP</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tableCanvas">
      <tr ng-repeat="people in search.info" ng-class-even="'even'">
        <td></td>
        <td>{{people.id}}</td>
        <td>{{people.nickname}}</td>
        <td>{{people.email}}</td>
        <td>{{people.lastIp}}</td>
        <td>{{people.regIp}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</main>
```

So far, this is what I've done. Also, I've linked a JSFiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/ho00cLkk/

Please let me know if what I am asking is confusing or not clear.

Comment: In your template, you have `people in people.info`, where you probably wanted to have `people in search.info`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that your question consists of two separate parts:

1. How do I filter the displayed items?
2. How do I hide all results until the first search is made?

As the second question seems uninteresting to me (many possible solutions, no general problem), I'll focus on the first one. You might want to read the documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter . Then it's pretty simple and you don't even need any submit buttons:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Name
                <input type="text" ng-model="searchProps.name">
            </th>
            ...
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="person in people | filter:searchProps">
            ...
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

(where `people` is your `search.info`). Table rows will be automatically filtered to contain only the items with properties partially matching the values in `searchProps`.

CodePen example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jEEZaa